# What's the difference between a commission fee and an artificially inflated spread when executing a trade?

Tags: trading, cryptocurrency, fees, spreads, fidelity

I read on https://www.kitco.com/news/2022-11-29/Fidelity-Crypto-is-a-go-4-5-trillion-firm-launches-retail-crypto-trading.html:

> The platform promises “commission free” crypto trades, but the company said “a spread of 1% will be factored into every trade execution price.” Fidelity said that 1% is the maximum rate, and they may choose to apply a lower spread percentage or no spread at the beginning.

What's the difference between a commission fee and an artificially inflated spread when executing a trade?

Answer (score 4):

> What's the difference between a commission fee and an artificially inflated spread when executing a trade?

Conceptually - none. That's how they make money. Practically - they make it *seem* like they're not taking any cut from the trades, but they are.

Here's [an article that explains it in details](https://www.theforexguy.com/calculate-forex-spread-bid-ask-price/). They use Forex as an example, but it doesn't really matter - the principle is exactly the same.